# Why Eslint don't see global TypeScript types in .vue files (no-undef)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

I have a global type in my Vue/TypeScript project. In the `.ts` files, everything is fine, and Eslint sees it, but in the `.vue` files, Eslint throws error that the type is not defined. TypeScript does not throw any errors and sees this type. Configs and code sample below.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@hse-design/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@hse-design/vue": "^1.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "element-ui": "^2.12.0",
    "faker": "^5.1.0",
    "focus-visible": "^5.2.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "path-to-regexp": "^6.2.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "sanitize.css": "^12.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.6",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^9.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.2",
    "vue-svgicon": "^3.2.6",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1",
    "vuex-class": "^0.3.2",
    "vuex-module-decorators": "^1.0.1",
    "yamljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/faker": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.21",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.165",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.2",
    "@types/node": "~14.14.35",
    "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.14.0",
    "@types/yamljs": "^0.2.31",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "concurrently": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.12.0",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.9.0",
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "sass": "^1.22.10",
    "sass-loader": "10.1.1",
    "style-resources-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "swagger-routes-express": "^3.2.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-element": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-style-resources-loader": "^0.1.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^5.28.0"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest",
      "webpack-env",
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/@types",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [ "src/**/*", "tests/**/*" ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

**.eslint.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    es6: true
  },
  parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaVersion: 2020
  },
  plugins: [
    'vue'
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'class-methods-use-this': 0,
    'consistent-return': 0,
    'import/no-cycle': 0,
    'import/extensions': 0,
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 0,
    'space-before-function-paren': [2, 'never'],
    'vue/array-bracket-spacing': 'error',
    'vue/arrow-spacing': 'error',
    'vue/block-spacing': 'error',
    'vue/brace-style': 'error',
    'vue/camelcase': 'error',
    'vue/comma-dangle': 'error',
    'vue/component-name-in-template-casing': 'error',
    'vue/eqeqeq': 'error',
    'vue/key-spacing': 'error',
    'vue/match-component-file-name': 'error',
    'vue/object-curly-spacing': 'error',
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': ['error', {
      singleline: 3,
      multiline: {
        max: 1,
        allowFirstLine: false
      }
    }]
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'airbnb-base',
    'plugin:vue/recommended',
    '@vue/standard',
    '@vue/typescript'
  ]
}
```

**src/@types/typings.d.ts**

```js
type MyType = {
  value: any
}
```

**src/App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({
  name: 'App',
})
export default class extends Vue {
  myField: MyType = { value: 1 } // The error is here | Ошибка здесь
</script>
```

**Error**

```
error: 'MyType' is not defined (no-undef) at src/App.vue:15:12:
  13 | })
  14 | export default class extends Vue {
> 15 |   myField: MyType = { value: 1 }
     |            ^
  16 | }
  17 | </script>
  18 |
```

Comment: Because there's no `declare` for this type?

Comment: @EstusFlask, I tried to `declare module` and it didn't help. I think if this were the case, the type would not be defined in the `.ts` files

Answer (score 12):

The [troubleshooting documentation of typescript-eslint has an entry](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting/#i-get-errors-from-the-no-undef-rule-about-global-variables-not-being-defined-even-though-there-are-no-typescript-errors) about this:

> The no-undef lint rule does not use TypeScript to determine the global variables that exist - instead, it relies upon ESLint's configuration.
>
> We strongly recommend that you do not use the no-undef lint rule on TypeScript projects. The checks it provides are already provided by TypeScript without the need for configuration - TypeScript just does this significantly better.

They recommend to disable `no-undef` for TypeScript by adding an override to your ESLint configuration like so:

```
overrides: [
  {
    files: ['*.ts', '*.vue'],
    rules: {
      'no-undef': 'off',
    },
  },
],
```

Please note that this disables `no-undef` for all `*.vue` files, regardless of whether they use TypeScript or JavaScript.

Comment: Doing this how do you avoid disabling no-undef for variables referenced in the script part? eg. console.log(notDef) won't be catched?

Comment: By sticking to TypeScript in '*.vue' files. The check is already provided by TypeScript.